# Set Expires Time in Cookie Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a string that I use to set expires date in cookie. But I always fail to set it. Here is my Code:

```
var expTime = '2016-06-09T03:06:53Z';
var valueCookie = 'test'; 
SetCookie('myCookie', valueCookie, expTime);


function SetCookie(name, value, expTime) {
document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; ' 'expires=' + expTime+ '; path=/';
```

};

Why I fail to set Expire Date in Cookie?

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

The parameters of the function above are the name of the cookie (cname), the value of the cookie (cvalue), and the number of days until the cookie should expire (exdays).

The function sets a cookie by adding together the cookiename, the cookie value, and the expires string.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code

```
function setCookie(name,value,data){
    var oDate =new Date();
    oDate.setDate(oDate.getDate()+data);
    document.cookie=name+'='+value+';expires='+oDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a syntax error.Try this

```
var expTime = '2016-06-09T03:06:53Z';
var valueCookie = 'test'; 
SetCookie('myCookie', valueCookie, expTime);


function SetCookie(name, value, expTime) {
document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + expTime+ '; path=/';
}
```